# Can soffit be installed at an angle?

Tags: soffit

The top of my windows are above the roof overhang and I want to install soffits without blocking the window.

It's a single story house with high windows. I want to cover the underside of the overhang.

Can the soffits be installed at an angle?

Comment: It's installed at an angle on every rake (gable overhang) in the modern world. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sloped soffits are fine:

[image]

Image: https://www.renovate.org.nz/1970s/roofs/eaves-gables-and-guttering/

Some consideration should be given to fire safety, which depends on the risk in your area:

> Use flat, horizontal soffits (see Figure 3) instead of attaching the soffits to the sloped joists, which creates sloped soffits. A flat soffit reduces the potential for entrapment of embers and hot gases.

Ref: https://www.firesafemarin.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/fema_p_737_fs_6.pdf